# is there any way to make annotations snap to a mesh?

Tags: grease-pencil, snapping

Is there any way I could use the grease pencil snap to the face of a model/plane? 
For example:
[image]

but then if I change the perspective the annotation is floating where it shouldn't
[image]

It would be much more useful if it could snap to faces, Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the *Tool Shelf* in the *3D View*.

Go to the *Grease Pencil* rider and under *Stroke Placement* select **Surface**.

[image: surface stroke placement]

Edit : For blender 2.8 it is in the popover menu.

[image: Popover menu Stroke placement]

Comment: thx, I'm using blender 2.8 but Its not hard to find based on this ^^.

Comment: @Diogo That's good to hear. You can edit this answer (or propose an edit) with additional information for 2.8 to make this answer helpful in a broader scope.